# C# Change TextBox background from another class

Tags: c#, wpf, class

I'm trying to change TextBox_Drukarki_Model background from class after PING. Code:

**MainWindow : MetroWindow**

```
private void Button_Drukarki_Sprawdz_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DrukarkaPing test = new DrukarkaPing(TextBox_Drukarki_IPNS.Text);
    test.CheckPing();
}
```

**Another class outside MainForm**

```
class DrukarkaPing
{
    private string adresip;
    private MainWindow _form;


    public DrukarkaPing(MainWindow MetroWindow)
    {
        _form = MetroWindow;
    }

    public DrukarkaPing(string adresip)
    {
        this.adresip = adresip;
    }

    public async void CheckPing()
    {
        try
        {
            Ping PingZapytanie = new Ping();
            PingReply PingOdp = PingZapytanie.Send(adresip);

            if (PingOdp.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                _form.TextBox_Drukarki_Model.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            }
            else
            {
                var window = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MetroWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
                if (window != null)
                    await window.ShowMessageAsync("Błąd!", "Błędny adres IP lub Netbios.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var window = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MetroWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (window != null)
                await window.ShowMessageAsync("Błąd!", e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

It's almost working but when IPStatus.Success, catch shows me Exception:
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object".
I have no idea what to change.I tried various combinations with MetroWindow, MainWindow or TextBox_Drukarki_Model in constructors.

**Update** Work now.

**Main:**

```
DrukarkaPing Sprawdznext = new DrukarkaPing(TextBox_Drukarki_IP.Text, TextBox_Drukarki_IPNS.Text);
Sprawdznext.CheckPing(TextBox_Drukarki_IP);
```

**CS:**

```
private string adresip;
private string test;

public TextBox TextBox_Drukarki_IP { get; set; }
public TextBox TextBox_Drukarki_IPNS { get; set; }

public DrukarkaPing(string adresip, string test)
{
    this.adresip = adresip;
    this.test = test;
}

public async void CheckPing(TextBox TextBox_Drukarki_IP)
{
    try
    {
        if (test == "" || test == " ")
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            Ping PingZapytanie = new Ping();
            PingReply PingOdp = PingZapytanie.Send(adresip);

            if (PingOdp.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                TextBox_Drukarki_IP.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            }
            else
            {
                TextBox_Drukarki_IP.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var window = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MetroWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (window != null)
            await window.ShowMessageAsync("Błąd!", e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you use the first constructor, replace with `test = new DrukarkaPing(this);`, BTW it's not the way of changing color of textbox, use DataBinding

Comment: You didn't set  `_form` field, so it's calling `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: Why do you pass TextBox_Drukarki_IPNS.Text to the constructor of DrukarkaPing? Does this even compile? And how is PingZapytanie.Send defined?

Comment: I pasted update. It looks like it works